# Building a box with packer that runs on vagrant-libvirt

Tags: debian, boot, qemu, vagrant, libvirt

I would like to build a Debian stretch to run on vagrant with the libvirt provider.

I have tried building from scratch and also with packer and the best I get is an "OS not found" error on the reboot or a freeze on the vagrant up of the box.

When **not** using packer I can boot the box inside virt-manager and it works but it gets no network access if I do a vagrant up on the same box. Packer is supposed to simplify that but I get a **no media found** error at boot.

Booting with Vagrant up it freezes at the point of:

> default: Waiting for domain to get an IP address.

If I then attach to the screen of the machine through `virt-manager` I see it frozen after:

> acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off

Where am I going wrong?

Is there a need for an extra manual step after the output of this packer script?

Here is the packer template I use:

```
{

"variables": {
    "user": "vagrant",
    "password": "vagrant",
    "disk_size": "100000",
    "domain": ""
},

"builders": [
    {
        "name": "debian93-vagrant",

        "type": "qemu",
        "format": "qcow2",
        "accelerator": "kvm",
        "disk_size": "{{ user `disk_size` }}",
    "iso_url": "https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/9.3.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-9.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso",
        "iso_checksum": "83480be837710a76fd4e75a6573ca110e06f5a7589d2d3852bdb0f45749800b3",
        "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",

        "http_directory": "http",

        "ssh_username": "{{ user `user` }}",
        "ssh_password": "{{ user `password` }}",
        "shutdown_command": "echo '{{ user `password` }}' | sudo -S shutdown -h now",

        "ssh_wait_timeout": "60m",

        "boot_wait": "2s",
        "boot_command": [
               "<esc><wait><wait>",
               "install ",

               "auto=true ",
               "priority=critical ",
               "interface=auto ",
               "url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg ",

               "passwd/user-fullname={{ user `user` }} ",
               "passwd/user-password={{ user `password` }} ",
               "passwd/user-password-again={{ user `password` }} ",
               "passwd/username={{ user `user` }} ",

               "<enter>"
        ]
    }
],

"provisioners": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "execute_command": "echo '{{ user `password` }}' | {{ .Vars }} sudo -E -S bash '{{ .Path }}'",
        "scripts": [
            "scripts/vagrant.sh",
            "scripts/update.sh",
            "scripts/packages.sh",
            "scripts/cleanup.sh"
        ]
    }
],

    "post-processors": [
    {
        "keep_input_artifact": false,
        "output": "box/debian93-vagrant.box",
        "type": "vagrant"
    }
]

}
```

And the Vagrant file to boot it up:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'libvirt'

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   # TODO build our own and deploy it to vagrantboxes
   # config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
   config.vm.box = "debian93Vagrant"
   # config.vm.box = ""
   #config.vm.box_version = "0.0.1"

   # Remove or adapt host_ip if remote access is required
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5601, host: 5601, host_ip:    "127.0.0.1"
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9200, host: 9200, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5044, host: 5044, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

   # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
   # using a specific IP.
   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.121.10"

   # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
   # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
   # your network.
   # config.vm.network "public_network"

   # If more folders are needed map them here
   # config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"


   config.vm.synced_folder "./config", "/config"

   # Libvirt provider with added oomph
   config.vm.provider :libvirt do |prov|
          prov.memory = 4096 
          prov.cpus = 4
   end

   # Basic setup through a shell provisioner
   config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        apt-get update
        apt-get upgrade -y
        apt-get install net-tools htop
        sleep 5
  SHELL

  # Deploy the stack
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |an|
        an.playbook = "./ansible/single_machine.yml"
  end

  # Leave things running permanently post installation
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    systemctl enable logstash 
    systemctl enable elasticsearch 
    systemctl enable kibana
    service kibana start
    service elasticsearch start
    service logstash start
 SHELL

end
```

Further investigation reveals the following mismatch in the MAC addresses:

- Inside the booted image (accessed through virt-manager): 52:54:00:a0:46:68
- In Vagrant (from debug output): mac="52:54:00:9e:ad:85"
- And from the error message: DEBUG wait_till_up: Searching for IP for MAC address: 52:54:00:b8:88:7d

Also the UUIDs of the domains are not the same:

- Vagrant gives: id="24e1487f-c36f-4cc3-a45e-4d8c6d867a4d"
- virt-manager reports: c4d152fd-6da4-4b09-bb98-96767b367a6c

What could cause the mismatch?

Comment: Also reported as an issue on github [https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/841]